# Avoiding width adjustment on mobile device

Tags: html, mobile

I am printing some plain text tables for my team.

As txt files are difficult to render for universal devices, I am passing the code into HTML files.

Everything is OK now except for Android and BB devices, because browsers are shrinking the tables, so they become unreadable.

I tried `<div style="width: 500px">` but this is just setting a maximum width, not a minimum.

Is there any way I can avoid my fixed width tables to be real fixed width?

My simple code, just as a reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<pre>

HERE GOES MY FIXED WIDTH TABLE

</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean that you need `min-width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the viewport window for mobile access with something like this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=d-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Substitute *d-width* with the actual pixel width of the device.